# Finding elements of a given group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Calculate how many elements are in the group  $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$
. The answer is 8 but i do not know how they get the answer. need help here

Comment: Hi @Lynnie, consider accepting the answers if they are helpful, if not, keep asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try showing that for any $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, $g \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}^{\times}$ if and only if $\gcd(g, 15) = 1$.

(Note that this can be used generally to characterize elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{m}^{\times}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$)